# ImportError: No module named run" in wsgi file while deploying flask app on apache running rhel 7 on ec2

Tags: python-2.7, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-restful

i'm trying to deploy my flask app on apache running on RHEl 7 on ec2. I get the import error in error_logs when i do curl http://localhost/ i have also printed the sys.path in wsgi file before importing 
my error log:

```
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.249918 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] ['/var/www/rest_api', '/var/www/rest_api', '/var/www/rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.250288 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] [remote ::1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=30698): Target WSGI script '/var/www/rest_api/example.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.250302 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] [remote ::1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=30698): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/rest_api/example.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.250317 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] [remote ::1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.250335 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] [remote ::1:0]   File "/var/www/rest_api/example.wsgi", line 15, in <module>
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.250388 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] [remote ::1:0]     from run import app as application
[Thu Feb 22 19:16:21.250404 2018] [:error] [pid 30698] [remote ::1:0] ImportError: No module named run
```

example.wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

activate_this = '/var/www/rest_api/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

logging.info(sys.path)

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/rest_api")

print sys.path
from run import app as application
```

run.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

from resources.insert import  blueprint
from resources.get import get_blueprint



app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(get_blueprint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

myapp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

WSGIProcessGroup rest_api
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptReloading On
WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIDaemonProcess rest_api python-path=/var/www/rest_api:/var/www/rest_api/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages  user=ec2-user group=ec2-user threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/rest_api/example.wsgi

<Directory /var/www/rest_api>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i'm using virtual environment with python 2.7

Comment: What is the full path to ``run.py``? What are the permissions on the file and the directory it is in?

Comment: /var/www/rest_api/run.py  both directory and script has permission 777

Comment: after printing os.path.dirname(sys.executable). I get output as: /usr/bin which means the virtualenv is not getting actiavte in wsgi file, so module error is occuring. check if my virtualenv declaration is correct in myapp.conf and example.wsgi

Comment: Under mod_wsgi the ``python`` executable isn't run and ``sys.executable`` is meaningless. Instead the Python shared library is linked into mod_wsgi and Python C API used to start the interpreter.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a directory ``/var/www/rest_api/run``. If you have that and ``run.py`` then Python will get confused as the sub directory will take precedence and if it doesn't contain ``__init__.py`` it will think no module exists.

Comment: my run file is under rest_api folder and also my example.wsgi is under rest_api folder.

Comment: Still i get the same error. I dont understand where i went wrong

Comment: Have you tried to rule out SELinux, by setting it to permissive (`#setenforce 0`) ? It is enabled by default on RHEL and will prevent WSGI scripts from importing some custom libraries.